# Using XSLT in the browser doesn't work, receiving error: End tag 'xsl:template' does not match the start tag 'xsl:for-each'

Tags: xml, xslt

The xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
<style>
body { 
background-color: #000000;
}
p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
color: #ffffff;
}
  <body>
<h1>Documentation</h1>
<hr/>
<xsl:for-each select="commands/command">
<h2><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h2>
<hr/>
<p><xsl:value-of select="usage"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="description"/></p>
<br/>
</xsl:template> <!-- error here -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="documentationstyle.xsl"?>
<commands>
<command>
<name>compile</name>
<usage>compile game loveexedir outfilename outdir</usage>
<description>Compiles a love game</description>
</command>
<command> 
<name>clear</name>
<usage>clear</usage>
<description>when i forget im using dos and not bash</description>
</command>
</commands>
```

On IE, it says:
End tag 'xsl:template' does not match the start tag 'xsl:for-each'. Error processing resource 'DIRECTORY CENSORED...

--^

On Google Chrome, it says nothing.
I'm a beginner to XSL and XML so....
Send help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On IE, it says: End tag 'xsl:template' does not match the start tag 'xsl:for-each'. Error processing resource 'DIRECTORY CENSORED...

The error is correct, you forgot to close `<xsl:for-each>`. XSLT is developed in XML, and XML must be well-formed to be, well, XML. To get it well-formed, each and every element must either be self-closed (as with `<br />`) or normally closed (as with `<xsl:for-each>... some code... </xsl:for-each>`).

There are more tags you have opened, but not closed: `script`, `body` and `html`. Here's a possible way of correcting those (and by indenting your code, it becomes easier to find such issues):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <style>
            body { 
            background-color: #000000;
            }
            p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
            color: #ffffff;
            }
            </style>

            <body>
                <h1>Documentation</h1>
                <hr/>
                <xsl:for-each select="commands/command">
                    <h2><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h2>
                    <hr/>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="usage"/></p>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="description"/></p>
                    <br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You [can see it in action here](http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7kU), which is generally a good way of testing your XSLT stylesheets prior to using them with a browser, because browser-based testing is next to impossible, their error messages, if any, are often of little use. Besides, most browsers (Chrome, Firefox) do not support running the XML + XSLT from a local drive, and either show an error or just an empty page.

There's a myriad of free and commercial tools around that can help you with context-sensitive help while developing XSLT, and that will make sure your XSLT is valid prior to even running it.